# I receive "ERROR: Port should be >= 0 and < 65536. Received NaN." on Elastic Beanstalk when using Sequelize CLI

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sequelize.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I'm trying to run `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate --env production` on an Elastic Beanstalk Node.js instance. The database settings are

```
  "production": {
    "username": "process.env.RDS_USERNAME",
    "password": "process.env.RDS_PASSWORD",
    "database": "process.env.RDS_DB_NAME",
    "host": "process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME",
    "port": "process.env.RDS_PORT",
```

When I attempt to run the command, I get the following output

```
npx sequelize-cli db:migrate --env production

Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.18.1, CLI: 6.6.0, ORM: 6.21.0]

Loaded configuration file "settings.json".
Using environment "production".

ERROR: Port should be >= 0 and < 65536. Received NaN.
```

I've logged `process.env.RDS_PORT` in the root of my application and am getting the following

```
console.log('process.env.RDS_PORT', process.env.RDS_PORT)
process.env.RDS_PORT 5432
```

I'm wondering how I can solve this issue.

**Dialect:** postgres

**Sequelize CLI version:** 6.6.0

**Sequelize version:** 6.21.0

Comment: Are you sure those `process.env.*` values are meant to be string literals?

Comment: Ah you're onto something, I realise there is a conditional when initialising the Sequelize instance that checks for this, which probably doesn't crossover for `sequelize-cli`. I'll see if I can find something in the docs.

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config)
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config)
}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `process.env.*` cannot be used as string literals. I realised I parse my config and `eval` if they have `process.env` as a part of their key.

Instead, I can pass `config.js` as config into `sequelize-cli`:

```
npx sequelize-cli db:migrate --config config.js --env production
```

```
// config.js
module.exports = {
  production: {
    username: process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.RDS_DB_NAME,
    host: process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
    port: process.env.RDS_PORT,
    dialect: 'postgres'
  }
}
```

**Update:**

Passing in `config.js` also didn't work on Elastic Beanstalk (possibly because `process.env.*` aren't available when running on the fly scripts). Instead, I constructed the connection string and passed it in, as [described here](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/blob/main/docs/README.md#configuration-connection-string).

```
sequelize db:migrate --url 'mysql://root:password@mysql_host.com/database_name'
```